# Does the standard error of the mean approach 0 as the number of samples increases?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, asymptotics, t-distribution

The standard error of the mean (SEM) is often given as $s / \sqrt n$, where $s$ is the standard deviation and $n$ the number of samples. Does this mean that if we were to calculate the SEM with more and more samples that the SEM would approach 0?

I ask because I feel like this would have implications for the t-distribution when defined as $ {\bar X - \mu \over s / \sqrt n} $, as it seems to me like this should cause the t-distribution to take increasingly larger values as the number of samples increases.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your concern about the t distribution? It sounds to me like you are wondering, perhaps, whether for larger sample sizes the t distribution becomes more likely to take on very large values?

Comment: If $\mu_X=E(\bar{X})$ were not the same as $\mu$ in that numerator term, it would be the case that the t-statistic would tend to be larger (indeed, that's why the t-test has power that increases with larger sample size when the null is false). But when the null is true, then $E(\bar{X}-\mu)=0$, while $s/\sqrt{n}$ is an estimate of the standard deviation of the difference $\bar{X}-\mu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  $S_n / \sqrt{n} \to 0$ since $S_n \to \sigma$, which is a constant.  But notice that $(\bar{X_n} - \mu) \to 0$ as well, so we don't expect $\sqrt{n} |\bar{X_n} - \mu| / S_n \to \infty$.  Basically the two terms converge to zero at the same rate so their ratio has a stable distribution even as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: ... assuming some usually reasonable technical hypotheses are met.  (I'm not saying they are or are not important.  I'm just saying they exist and shouldn't be entirely ignored.  For an example, consider the sample moments of Cauchy distributed data when increasing sample size.)

Comment: @EricTowers True, but I think those conditions are given since the poster was assuming $\sqrt{n} (\bar{X} - \mu) / S$ actually follows a $t$ distribution.